# SQL Inner Join On Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

I have a Join

```
SELECT * FROM Y
INNER JOIN X ON ISNULL(X.QID, 0) = ISNULL(y.QID, 0)
```

`Isnull` in a Join like this makes it slow.  It's like having a conditional Join.
Is there any work around to something like this?
I have a lot of records where `QID` is Null

Anyone have a work around that doesn't entail modifying the data

Comment: For what database (including version)?

Comment: Only SQL Server and Access have `ISNULL()`, so I'd assume SQL Server

Comment: Is it safe to assume that in both X and Y QID could be any value including NULL and 0, but that NULL and 0 are to be considered equal?

Comment: Did you mean to have `X.QID = Y.QID` before the `AND`?

Comment: MySQL has an entirely different `ISNULL` function; the syntax used here is usually spelled `COALESCE`.  Then again, MySQL also has the `<=>` operator, which won't help for this question.

Comment: Does the QID column contain lots of null in both tables?  If so you effectively will get a crossjoin on the null columns which seems like a funny result.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a query plan, I think the comments are just over analyzing what is probably happening. The `ISNULL()` is effectively byassing the index. This is a fairly novice query written poorly: Not hard to fix, but it just bit him. There is construct for this I've given both of them in my answer.

Comment: yes qid does contain lots of nulls and 0 and Null are meant to be equal

Comment: I am sorry there are other parts to this join that would make it not a cross join.  This is a small part of a huge beast of a view.

Comment: Sounds like you ought to be storing zeros and not nulls in the field. Logically Null is not equal to Null in databases.

Comment: you may be correct in that, but thats not really an option at this point.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have two options

```
INNER JOIN x
   ON x.qid = y.qid OR (x.qid IS NULL AND y.qid IS NULL)
```

or easier

```
INNER JOIN x
  ON x.qid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y.qid
```

Comment: Certainly, the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` can not be slower, so I would go with it. But neither of these should be /slow/. You would have to be talking about a fairly massive data set for it to matter.

Comment: hmm evan as you can probably understand this is a smaller version of a much larger view.  As you stated it what is shown above is a novice problem that has gotten away from me.  While i don't want to air my view all over the place do you have a minute to look at it maybe and help me patch the wound...

Comment: sure you can contact me on irc. EvanCarroll on freenode.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM" feature not available in SQL Server?  From what I can find, it will likely make it into the next release, but it's not in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Garland yes, there is no `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` in SQL Server

Comment: -1 Then why is this the voted and most rated answer? The first option doesn't appear to work either as I get "The multi-part identifier "dbo.tbl_MyTable" could not be bound."

Comment: Snap! Telling it like it is

Comment: What is the meaning of below query( b.field is null??)

select *
from table1 a left join
table 2 b on a.id = b.id and b.field is null

b.field is null what it will do in join condition

Comment: `IS NULL x` evaluates to true *if and only if* x is null. `true` is a value like all others. the `trues` on the left and the `true` on the right will be cross-joined.

Comment: Greetings from the year 2022: I'm pleased to say that SQL Server 2022 now finally supports `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Dai If you want to know where SQL Server will be going in the next 20 years, you can download the beta version today at https://postgresql.org/ they just have to add telemetry/spyware and work C# into it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll _har-har_ - yes, Postgres is probably the best overall RDBMS right now, but there's a lot of features that MSSQL Server has that Postgres stilll lacks (at least until Postgres 15 comes out), like `MERGE` and indexed-views (Postgres' Materialized Views require manual updates, SQL Server's don't).

Answer (score 11):

If you want null values to be included from Y.QID then Fastest way is

`SELECT * FROM Y
LEFT JOIN X ON y.QID = X.QID`

Note: this solution is applicable only if you need null values from Left table i.e. Y (in above case).

Otherwise

`INNER JOIN x ON x.qid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y.qid`

is right way to do

Answer (score 9):

[This article has a good discussion on this issue](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx). You can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Y
INNER JOIN X ON EXISTS(SELECT X.QID 
                       INTERSECT 
                       SELECT y.QID);
```

Comment: Any comparison on query plans on this versus `ISNULL()`? I couldn't see much difference on a sample data set, but I like the simplicity for multicolumn joins.

Comment: @ThomasG.Mayfield - `ISNULL` kills index use. e.g. compare the plans for `CREATE TABLE #T(X INT UNIQUE); SELECT * FROM #T T1 INNER MERGE JOIN  #T T2 ON EXISTS(SELECT T1.X INTERSECT SELECT T2.X);SELECT * FROM #T T1 INNER MERGE JOIN  #T T2 ON ISNULL(T1.X,-1) = ISNULL(T2.X,-1);SELECT * FROM #T T1 INNER LOOP JOIN  #T T2 ON EXISTS(SELECT T1.X INTERSECT SELECT T2.X);SELECT * FROM #T T1 INNER LOOP JOIN  #T T2 ON ISNULL(T1.X,-1) = ISNULL(T2.X,-1);DROP TABLE #T` - the merge version can't use the index order and needs a sort and the nested loops scans the inner input rather than seeking it.

Comment: I´ve used this intersect trick all the time, but it seems that SQL Server 2016 optimizer doesn´t like it much. I have to investigate it more though,

Comment: @RomanPekar - If you find an example where it is optimised badly I'd be interested to see it

Comment: @MartinSmith if I manage to find some time to make a good example, I'm going to create a question on SO.

Comment: @RomanPekar - sometimes using `NOT EXISTS` and `EXCEPT` is optimised better than this version. Although sometimes it *is* just best to write it out the long winded way. `X.QID = Y.QID OR (X.QID IS NULL AND Y.QID IS NULL)`

Answer (score 6):

Are you committed to using the Inner join syntax?

If not you could use this alternative syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Y,X
WHERE (X.QID=Y.QID) or (X.QUID is null and Y.QUID is null)
```

Comment: There's no benefit over using this syntax rather than the explicit join in the accepted answer though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the join doesn't even do what you want. If there are 100 records in table a with a null qid and 100 records in table b with a null qid, then the join as written should make a cross join and give 10,000 results for those records.  If you look at the following code and run the examples, I think that the last one is probably more the result set you intended:

```
create table #test1 (id int identity, qid int)
create table #test2 (id int identity, qid int)

Insert #test1 (qid)
select null
union all
select null
union all
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select null

Insert #test2 (qid)
select null
union all
select null
union all
select 1
union all
select 3
union all
select null


select * from #test2 t2
join #test1 t1 on t2.qid = t1.qid

select * from #test2 t2
join #test1 t1 on isnull(t2.qid, 0) = isnull(t1.qid, 0)


select * from #test2 t2
join #test1 t1 on 
 t1.qid = t2.qid OR ( t1.qid IS NULL AND t2.qid IS NULL )


select t2.id, t2.qid, t1.id, t1.qid from #test2 t2
join #test1 t1 on t2.qid = t1.qid
union all
select null, null,id, qid from #test1 where qid is null
union all
select id, qid, null, null from #test2  where qid is null
```

Comment: My Current Join does what I want it just does it inneficiently.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want a cross join on the null ids?

Answer (score 1):

Hey it is kind of late to answer that but I got the same question, what I realized is that you must have a record with the ID of `0` in you second table to make this :

```
SELECT * FROM Y
INNER JOIN X ON ISNULL(Y.QID, 0) = ISNULL(X.QID, 0)
```

to happen, it actually says `if there is none, then use 0`. **BUT** what if `Y` table does **NOT** have a record with the ID of `0`?

So, I found this method, (and worked for my case):

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(Y.QName, 'ThereIsNone') AS YTableQName
FROM
  X
LEFT OUTER JOIN Y ON X.QID = Y.QID
```

[A snapshot of my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXEFy.png)

This way you **DON'T** need a record with `0` ID value in your second table (which is `Y` in this case and `Customers` in my case), OR any record at all

**UPDATE**:

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071829/sql-server-join-two-tables-and-return-with-null-records) post for better understanding.

Comment: your first thing seems to be doing fine for me. I dont get the problem you have with it. I want to join if both are null, so both will be 0. I dont need one of the tables to have a 0 already

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want to join two tables together where their QID columns are both *not* null, correct? However, you aren't enforcing any other conditions, such as that the two QID values (which seems strange to me, but ok). Something as simple as the following (tested in MySQL) seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `Y` INNER JOIN `X` ON (`Y`.`QID` IS NOT NULL AND `X`.`QID` IS NOT NULL);
```

This gives you every non-null row in Y joined to every non-null row in X.

**Update:** Rico says he also wants the rows with NULL values, why not just:

```
SELECT * FROM `Y` INNER JOIN `X`;
```

Comment: That is incorrect..  if is ay were y.qid = x.qid it will give me only rows that are not null.. I want the rows where they are both null as welll.

Comment: let me see if i can come up with a more precise example to clear the issues

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the [coalesce](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) function. I tested this in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html), but it should also work for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) or [MS SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

```
INNER JOIN x ON coalesce(x.qid, -1) = coalesce(y.qid, -1)
```

This will replace `NULL` with `-1` before evaluating it. Hence there must be no `-1` in `qid`.