# SQL Server : Join Two Tables and Return With Null Records

Tags: sql-server

I couldn't figure out how to join these two tables and get the result with NULL value that I want. I played around with `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN`..., but couldn't get it to work. Please see this below.

**Table1**:

```
NameID  Name
1       N1
2       N2
3       N3
4       N4
5       N5
```

**Table2**:

```
NameID  AnotherID   Value
1       AID-111     1000
2       AID-222     2000
2       AID-222     3000
3       AID-333     4000
4       AID-444     5000


Select ...
JOIN Table1 and Table2
WHERE AnotherID = 'AID-222'
```

This is the result I want:

```
NameID  Name    AnotherID   VALUE
1       N1      NULL        NULL
2       N2      AID-222     2000
3       N3      AID-222     3000    
4       N4      NULL        NULL    
5       N5      NULL        NULL
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect to also return AID-111 for NameID 1, AID-333 for NameID 3, etc.?  Your example result set isn't really a JOIN at all.

Comment: Why do you only want to return the value of `2000`? Why not `3000`?

Comment: @bluefeet, why? Let's say user has option to fill out up to 5 buckets (Table1), and Table2 is keeping track of buckets have have value. So, user initially fill in N2 = 2000, the leave the rest 4 empty. Next, user click "update buckets", it will open all 5 buckets, which has N2 = 2000, and user can fill in other empty buckets. I hope it makes sense.. sorry

Comment: In your listing of Table2, there are two entries for NameID2, both with AnotherID AID-222, but with different values: 2000 and 3000. What is it about 2000 that means you want that row to be returned, but not the 3000 row?

Comment: @vinceboydren, you're right. I want to return both 2000 and 3000. I have updated the above sample data. bluefeet's solution works perfect for me, all I need is remove the MIN(value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not explain why you want to return the value of `2000` instead of `3000` but you can use a `LEFT JOIN`  with a subquery to get the result:

```
select t1.nameid,
  t1.name,
  t2.anotherid,
  t2.value
from table1 t1
left join
(
  select nameid, anotherid, min(value) value
  from table2
  where anotherid = 'AID-222'
  group by nameid, anotherid
) t2
  on t1.nameid = t2.nameid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17e5a/5).  This gives the result:

```
| NAMEID | NAME | ANOTHERID |  VALUE |
--------------------------------------
|      1 |   N1 |    (null) | (null) |
|      2 |   N2 |   AID-222 |   2000 |
|      3 |   N3 |    (null) | (null) |
|      4 |   N4 |    (null) | (null) |
|      5 |   N5 |    (null) | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use full join,it will give your answer too:

Select t1.nameid,t1.name,t2.anotherid,t2.value from `tableA` t1

```
full outer join
(
    select nameid,anotherid,value from tableB 
    where anotherid IN ('AID-222','AID-333') 

) t2 
on t1.nameid = t2.nameid;
```