# SQL Server: Join Three Tables and Return With Null Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know how to join this tree tables for the expected result. I was testing with `LEFT / RIGHT / INNER / OUTER` joins but i can get the row with the "null" value.

I was playing wiht this tables:

**Games Table:**

```
Title    id
------------
Halo     1
Portal   2
Mario    3
```

**Genres Table:**

```
Name     id
------------
Action   1
FPS      2
MMO      3
Arcade   4
Puzzle   5
```

**Genres for games table:**

```
GameId     GenreId
------------------
1          1
1          2
3          5
```

This is what i get:

```
Title       Genre
-----------------
Halo        Action
Halo        FPS
Mario      Puzzle
```

This is the result i want:

```
Title       Genre
-----------------
Halo        Action
Halo        FPS
Portal      NULL
Mario      Puzzle
```

Note: I read this question: [SQL Server : Join Two Tables and Return With Null Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071829/sql-server-join-two-tables-and-return-with-null-records) but no helps me.

Please, some kind of help!

Comment: What you need is [OUTER JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)s.

Comment: Isn't that a `full outer join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need left (outer) joins to do this:

```
SELECT Games.Title, Genres.Name
FROM Games
LEFT JOIN GameGenres ON Games.Id = GameGenres.GameId
LEFT JOIN Genres ON GameGenres.GenreId = Genres.Id
```