# Laravel 5.7 join query with Null relatiion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a relation BookUser(one) to Book(many).
one Book model, 'borrowing_user_id' (if null mean book is available).

I tried to set it as below query, but this query does not show the available books, only show that borrowing books.How can I set a john query for all book?

```
    $query = Book::select( 'books.*')
    ->john( 'bookUsers' , 'bookUsers.id' , '=', 'books.borrowing_user_id' );
    /**
    query result
    books.book_name | books.borrowing_user_id | bookUsers.name
    BookA           | 1                       | Tom
    BookC           | 5                       | Peter
    */
```

My want result just like as below

```
books.book_name | books.borrowing_user_id | bookUsers.name
BookA           | 1                       | Tom
BookB           | Null                    | Null
BookC           | 5                       | Peter
```

BookUser model

```
class BookUser extends Model 
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
        ,'created_at'
        ,'updated_at'
        ,'deleted_at'
    ];
}

public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'borrowing_user_id', 'id');
}
```

Book model

```
class Book extends Model 
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'borrowing_user_id'  //nullable
        ,'book_name'
        ,'created_at'
        ,'updated_at'
        ,'deleted_at'
    ];
}

public function borrowing_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'borrowing_user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `john` not `join`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have the same model?

```
 $query = Book::with(['borrowing_user'=>function($query){
 $query->select('id','what_ever your next query);
 }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I solve this issue by myself.

[SQL Server : Join Two Tables and Return With Null Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071829/sql-server-join-two-tables-and-return-with-null-records)

use leftJoin.

```
$query = Book::select( 'books.*')
    ->leftJoin( 'bookUsers' , 'bookUsers.id' , '=', 'books.borrowing_user_id' );
```