# Not equal to is not working in sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have tried to get the data from tables using below query but its not working..

```
    SELECT
    ProductMaster.ProductName + '(' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), 0) + ')' AS orderedproducts,
    BranchName + '(' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), SUM(StockInward.Qty)) + ')' AS currentstock,
    Setup.Id AS BranchId
FROM ProductMaster
INNER JOIN StockOutward
    ON ProductMaster.Productid = StockOutward.productid
INNER JOIN stockinward
    ON ProductMaster.Productid = stockinward.productid
    AND stockinward.StockLocation <> StockOutward.Location
INNER JOIN Setup
    ON stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id
WHERE StockOutward.ProductId = '7'
GROUP BY    ProductMaster.ProductName,
            StockOutward.Qty,
            BranchName,
            Setup.Id
```

It is displaying all the records from the table `StockOutward`.

Comment: Some example data might help !

Comment: Please either simplify this to take out any joins that are unrelated to the problem, or state that, for example, the inner join with `Setup on stockinward.stocklocation = Setup.id` is necessary to reproduce the problem!

Comment: Can `ProductMaster.Productid` be NULL?

Comment: If yes, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202172/sql-inner-join-on-null-values

Comment: Should the 7 be in apostrophes?

Answer (score 0):

Try In your Inner join move your  <> in a where clause.
And in your sample, have you try more simple query (select 1 simple element and add one by one innerjoin.

Comment: An `INNER JOIN` clause and the `WHERE` clause are the same, so there's no use of moving the condition.

Comment: yes but : 'stockinward.StockLocation <> StockOutward.Location' better to put a where clause with a NOT IN instruction. No? like ' where stockinward.StockLocation not in (select StockOutward.Location...) with more optimization