# MS Access INNER/LEFT JOIN on NULL values

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, join

I have two tables.

The first one is: **Project Table**

```
 ID |    SN    | pTypeID
----|----------|-------
 1  | project1 |   1 
 2  | project2 |   3
 3  | project3 |  NULL
 4  | project4 |  NULL
```

and the second one is: **pType Table**

```
 ID |  Name   
----|---------
 1  | pType1 
 2  | pType2 
 3  | ptype3
```

I want to make a query that will return the following

```
 ID |    SN    |  Name
----|----------|--------
 1  | project1 | pType1 
 2  | project2 | pType3
 3  | project3 |  NULL
 4  | project4 |  NULL
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Project.ID, Project.SN, pType.Name
FROM Project
INNER JOIN Type ON Project.pTypeID = pType.ID
```

But I get an error saying "No Value given for one or more parameters".

After some research, I suspect that the error is produced by the NULL values in the Project table. I also tried with Left Joins and got the same error.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202172/sql-inner-join-on-null-values) but the solution doesn't work in Access apparently.

I am doing this in Excel with VBA. I am connecting to an Access ".accdb" database using ADODB connections.

Here is my question: is there any efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: In the inner join you have `Type` but shouldn't this be `pType`?

Comment: is mit because you need INNER JOIN pType (instead of Inner Join Type)?

Comment: What's wrong with a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Oh yes, it was a simple typo. Have to get some sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to left join on pType

```
select p.id, p.sn, t.name 
from Project as p 
    left join pType as t on p.pTypeID = t.id;
```

Comment: yes you are right, the left join should work. but the issue here was a typo. thank you!