# Inner JOIN with null ids

Tags: sql

we are doing a programming exercise: [SQL with Sailor Moon.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ab7a736edbcfc8e62000007).

We are trying to join three tables.

First we have tried to join by id:

```
select senshi_name as sailor_senshi, real_name_jpn as real_name, cats.name
from sailorsenshi 
INNER JOIN cats ON (cats.id = sailorsenshi.cat_id)
INNER JOIN schools ON (schools.id = sailorsenshi.school_id);
```

We see that the results after executing this query are:

```
sailor_senshi    real_name      name
Sailor Moon      Usagi Tsukino  Luna
Sailor Mercury   Ami Mizuno     Luna
Sailor Mars Rei  Hino           Luna
Sailor Jupiter   Makoto Kino    Luna
Sailor Venus     Minako Aino    Artemis
```

This result is wrong, because of we should get 10 rows, and we have 5 rows.

We have thought that the previous result is due to some cats_id are null:

```
select * from sailorsenshi;
```

[image]

Then we read the following topic:
[SQL Inner Join On Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202172/sql-inner-join-on-null-values)

And we tried:

```
select senshi_name as sailor_senshi, real_name_jpn as real_name, cats.name
from sailorsenshi 
INNER JOIN cats ON (cats.id = sailorsenshi.cat_id) OR sailorsenshi.cat_id is null
INNER JOIN schools ON (schools.id = sailorsenshi.school_id);
```

[image]

We observe that the rows in the table sailorsenshi are being matched with all cats' names in cats table:

```
select * from cats;
```

The result is:

```
id  name
1   Luna
2   Artemis
```

How could we get the rows from sailorsenshi which are duplicated, just once?

Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Also, add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i came up with.

I used the sailorsenshi table as kind of a base table, then changed out your inner joins to left joins, then made sure the sailorsenshi was on the left side of the join clause. Also, i noticed you didn't alias the cat column, and the school column wasn't present so i added them in there.

```
select 
    senshi_name sailor_senshi
    ,real_name_jpn real_name
    ,cats.name cat
    ,schools.school school
from sailorsenshi 
LEFT JOIN 
  cats ON (sailorsenshi.cat_id = cats.id)
LEFT JOIN schools ON (sailorsenshi.school_id = schools.id);
```

This should return your expected results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `left join`s:

```
select senshi_name as sailor_senshi, real_name_jpn as real_name, cats.name
from sailorsenshi ss LEFT JOIN
     cats c
     ON c.id = ss.cat_id LEFT JOIN
     schools s
     ON s.id = ss.school_id;
```

Note:  I gave all the tables convenient aliases.  You should qualify *all* columns references in the query, not just the ones in the `ON` clauses.