# why CTE returns wrong join values for null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

My source data is following

```
declare @t1 TABLE (vendor int, service varchar (10), site int, invoice int,
period int, fromDate date, toDate date, account int, cost decimal(19,2));
INSERT INTO @t1
Select *
from
(
VALUES 
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01','2017-01-31', null, 1064.64),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', null, 0),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', null, 0),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', null, 0)
) t (vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, cost)
```

I am doing a transformation on this like following

```
--base table--
; with ctebase as (
select 
vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, cost
from @t1)
--second base--
, cte0 as (select 
vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account from @t1
group by vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account
)
--average cost--
, cte1 as (
select vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account
,sum(Cost)/NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day, fromDate, toDate)+1,0) CostPerDay
from ctebase 
group by vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account
)
--expand row--
, cte2 as (
select 
vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, fromDate as Dates, YEAR (fromDate) as [Year], MONTH(fromDate) as [Month] from cte0
UNION ALL
select 
vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, DATEADD(day,1,Dates), YEAR(DATEADD(day,1,Dates)) as [Year], MONTH(DATEADD(day,1,Dates)) as [Month] from cte2
where Dates<toDate
)
--count aggregation--
, cte3 as (
select vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, Year, Month, COUNT(CONVERT(varchar(4),Year)+'-'+CONVERT(varchar(2),Month)) as [COUNT by YR-MO]
from cte2
group by vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, Year, Month
)
--join--
, cte4 as (
select a.vendor, a.service, a.site, a.invoice, a.period, a.fromDate,a.toDate,a.account,a.Year,a.Month, a.[COUNT by YR-MO],b.CostPerDay
from cte3 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte1 b 
ON 
a.vendor=b.vendor and a.service=b.service and a.site=b.site and a.invoice=b.invoice
and a.period=b.period and a.fromDate=b.fromDate and a.toDate=b.toDate and a.account=b.account
)
```

When I do `select * from cte4` I get following with `NULL` as return value for `CostPerDay`

| vendor | service | site | invoice | period | fromDate | toDate | account | Year | Month | COUNT by YR-MO | CostPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 467 | repair | 765321 | 8875 | 201701 | 1/1/2017 | 1/31/2017 | NULL | 2017 | 1 | 31 | NULL |

while I was expecting that value to be `34.343225` as `cte3` and `cte1` are respectively  following

| vendor | service | site | invoice | period | fromDate | toDate | account | Year | Month | COUNT by YR-MO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 467 | repair | 765321 | 8875 | 201701 | 1/1/2017 | 1/31/2017 | NULL | 2017 | 1 | 31 |

| vendor | service | site | invoice | period | fromDate | toDate | account | CostPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 467 | repair | 765321 | 8875 | 201701 | 1/1/2017 | 1/31/2017 | NULL | 34.343225 |

However, if I change the `account` value to a `non-null` value it works, like following

```
declare @t1 TABLE (vendor int, service varchar (10), site int, invoice int,
period int, fromDate date, toDate date, account int, cost decimal(19,2));
INSERT INTO @t1
Select *
from
(
VALUES 
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01','2017-01-31', 1, 1064.64),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', 1, 0),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', 1, 0),
(467, 'repair', 765321, 8875, 201701, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-31', 1, 0)
) t (vendor, service, site, invoice, period, fromDate, toDate, account, cost)
```

I am performing this transformation on a SQLDB table and there will be circumstances with account value `null`. How can I ensure that my final join returns correct value (expected value) in those circumstances?

Comment: `NULL = NULL` *does not* equal TRUE, it returns UNKNOWN, and thus `a.account = b.account` also is not true, and so your `LEFT JOIN` does not return a row.

Comment: Also in `cte0` you have a `GROUP BY` but no aggregation; I doubt that is intended. If it is, use `SELECT DISTINCT` as having a `GROUP BY` implies aggregation.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the suggestion, I did not use `DISTINCT` thinking it may have performance implication. But I can try. Also, coming back to the question, in cases when I have account value as `null` how can I make this query work to give me what I want?

Comment: A `GROUP BY` on *all* the columns is effectively the same as a `DISTINCT`; they will both be as (un)performant as the other.

Comment: I can change the join condition to `ISNULL(a.account,999999)=ISNULL(b.account,999999)` and it returns expected value. But I am not sure whether it is going to have any performance implications.

Comment: It will. If you want to match `NULL` to `NULL` you need to use `OR` logic and `IS NULL`. I.e. `AND (A.Col = B.Col OR (A.Col IS NULL AND B.Col IS NULL))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values) The solution there is very performant

Comment: To be honest, I think there are far better ways of writing this query anyway: query the table once, and do the aggregation in a `CROSS APPLY`, utilizing [Itzik Ben-gan's tally function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).  To get one date per month you can use `EOMONTH`.

Comment: As per @Charlieface's suggestion, to handle nulls in the existing query, I can either use `LEFT OUTER JOIN cte1 b ON ......and a.toDate=b.toDate and IIF(a.accountNbr is null,1,0)=IIF(b.accountNbr is null,1,0))` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN cte1 b ON ......and a.toDate=b.toDate and `exists (select a.accountNbr intersect select b.accountNbr))` .     However, in my case `IIF` gives better performance. One more useful resource for this is [Handling Nulls in Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202172/sql-inner-join-on-null-values).